# regularity of weak solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

For $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $d\geq 1$, by Riesz representation theorem we know that there exists unique $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that
$$<u,\phi>=<f,\phi>,\quad \forall \phi \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$$ 
then $u$ solves the equation 
$$-\Delta u +u =f$$ in the distribution sense.

My question is: how to obtain the regularity of solution $u$, i.e. how to prove that $u\in H^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$?.

Comment: The general idea is to show that the difference quotients of the first order weak derivatives of $u$ are bounded in $L^2$, which implies that they in turn have weak partial derivatives. This is a rather technical issue treated in PDE textbooks. I'd suggest taking a look at Evans.

Comment: the existence of weak solution is quite easy from Riesz theorem. Please focus on my last question: $u\in H^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$?. Thanks.

Comment: My comment addressed your last question.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand too much, could you explain more, please?. Which chapter in Evans' book do you suggest?, that is a huge book!.

Comment: In the edition I have, it appears to be covered in detail in section 6.3.

Comment: I took a look section 6.3 Regularity which contains Interior Regularity  and Boundary Regularity. But the problems above is Regularity on whole space $\mathbb{R}^d$

Comment: The techniques are essentially the same, follow the proofs.